# Is there a way to run selenium Java scripts without installing Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I built several selenium Java scripts and each class represents a test and I also built nice UI that allows the users to select which test they want to run. All the classes are under the same project/package
I am trying to deploy this UI to end users so that they can run it to select the tests without having to install Eclipse. This will make it so easy for me to deploy it to end users.

Is this double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the instruction to run it from command line as follows

java -jar filename.jar
ex:

java -jar program1.jar
the program1 consist of the followings are:

program1.class file
Resource library file such as SeleniumRC Server.jar and Selenium Java client.jar file
This method is applicable for SeleniumRC execution. We can directly create the program1.jar file from eclipse using File->Export.

I haven't tried it. Hope this helps

Comment: UI class is in UI.JAVA and it calls another class called quote that is in quote.java. Now, I want the user to execute UI.Java. If I use File->Export, should I use it for UI.Java file only?

Comment: If that file has the main method then it should work